# jQuery not reacting in Rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have a form that is creating messages to send to recipients, to which I am trying to add some jQuery to make it fancier to use. 
The first thing I would like to do is submit the form and display the message without reloading the page when the user presses the Enter key, but only when this particular textarea is focused. I now have a script that does that but only when clicking on the "send" button on the page.

I added the code below (I am new to jQuery and javascript so it might not be correct), but it doesn't react on the page. I then tried with simpler actions like only changing the css, like the outline of the textarea but nothing is happening neither.

So the problem that I see is that nothing happens with my jQuery code

Here is the code in my "show.js" file in assets/javascript/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#input_to_be_loaded').focus(function(){
    $('#input_to_be_loaded').css('outline-color','#ff0000');
  });

  $('#input_to_be_loaded').focus(function(){
    $(document).keydown(function(key) {
      switch(parseInt(key.which,10)) {

          // Enter key pressed
          case 13:
          /* get some values from elements on the page: */

          var $form = $("#message-form"),
          $submit = $form.find( 'button[type="submit"]' ),
          message_value = $form.find( 'input[name="micropost[content]"]' ).val(),
          recipient_value = $form.find( 'input[name="recipient[recipient_id]"]' ).val(),
          url = $form.attr('action');

          /* Send the data using post */
          var posting = $.post( url, { 
            recipient_id: recipient_value, 
            message: message_value 
          });
          $('#input_to_be_loaded').html("");
          break;
        }
      });
  });
});
```

Here is the form in my view:

```
<%= form_for(@micropost, remote: true, :method => :POST, id: "micropost_form_id") do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :recipient_id, :value => @user.id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :is_note, value: false %>

<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Press enter to send message", value: "",class: "form-control-messages",  id: "input_to_be_loaded" %>
</div>
<%= f.submit "Send", class: "btn btn-info", style: "float: right;" %>
<% end %>
```

and this is in the head of my application.html.erb file:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "show" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0' 
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'
gem 'faker', '1.1.2'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'
gem 'websocket-rails'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'

group :development, :test do 
    gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
    gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
    gem 'pry'
    gem 'pry-rails'
end

group :test do
    gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1' 
    gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
    gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
    gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
    gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
    gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

edit1: this is my controller code:

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery except: :show
  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    @user= User.find_by_id(@micropost.recipient_id) 
    if @micropost.is_note
      @old_notes= current_user.notes(@user).first
      if @old_notes
        @old_notes.destroy
      end
      @old_notes= current_user.notes(@user).first
    end
    if signed_in?
      @conversation_items = current_user.conversation(@user).paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 7)
    end
    @micropost.new = true
    if @micropost.save
      #flash[:success] = "You just sent a message to #{User.find_by_id(@micropost.recipient_id).name}"
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @user }
        format.js
      end

    else
      @feed_items = []
      redirect_to @user
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user=User.find_by_id(@micropost.recipient_id)
    @micropost.destroy
    redirect_to @user
  end

  private

  def micropost_params
    params.require(:micropost).permit(:content, :recipient_id, :new, :is_note)
  end

  def correct_user
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
    redirect_to root_url if @micropost.nil?
  end
end
```

the browser console gives:
http://s29.postimg.org/teg87878n/Screen_Shot_2014_03_20_at_14_18_51.png

Thank you in advance guys :)

Comment: And what do you see in developer console in your browser?

Comment: is the show.js in the assets directory? Please show your controller code.

Comment: show.js is in assets/javascript/ I added the controller code and the console output on this page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over-complicating it.
This should work:

```
$("#input_to_be_loaded").keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $form = $("#message-form"),
            $submit = $form.find('button[type="submit"]'),
            message_value = $form.find('input[name="micropost[content]"]').val(),
            recipient_value = $form.find('input[name="recipient[recipient_id]"]').val(),
            url = $form.attr('action');

        /* Send the data using post */
        var posting = $.post(url, {
            recipient_id: recipient_value,
            message: message_value
        });
        $('#input_to_be_loaded').html("");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Gms5d/1/

Comment: This looks way better now! TY! I added also a little css "test" changing the background color, which is working now! However for some reason the form is still not being submitted yet, and this message is displayed in the console when I press Enter: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" Would you have any guess where that could come from?

Comment: The error message might not be related to the form not being submitted, the same message appears when I click on the "send" button, which submits the form and displays the message.

Comment: It could be an issue with your routes in routes.rb

Comment: I think it is an issue with the post - the URL it is posting to. You are picking this up from the action attribute on the form, but you are not setting this in ruby. Or it is an issue with your routes in routes.rb

Comment: Actually I am getting this error message in the ruby console: 
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param not found: micropost):
  app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb:43:in `micropost_params'
  app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb:8:in `create'
How could I kindly request jQuery to pass the params in the "micropost" hash?

Comment: var posting = $.post(url, {
            recipient_id: recipient_value,
            micropost: message_value
        });

Comment: oop sorry, I meant this ":micropost": params.require(:micropost).permit(:content, :recipient_id, :new, :is_note)